# Optimized way to create OracleConnection and Command objects in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, singleton, database-connection, factory-pattern

I have the following code in DAL layer:

```
using(OracleConnection conn= new OracleConnection(connString))
using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql.ToString(), conn))
{
  conn.Open();
}
```

The above object creation is done at multiple places of DAL methods. I am looking if there is any way to optimize this object creation, instead of repeating it several times in my code.

Any suggestions/advise would be helpful.

Thanks,
WH

Answer (score 0):

There's really not a good way to do this without requiring almost the same amount of code each time to make sure you set it up properly because it needs to be disposable. Anything outside of this: using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql.ToString(), conn)) will despose the connection. Is there a reason why you can't move to using an ORM like Entity Framework? That aside you can create a class that will return a OracleConnection that you would then call .Open() on but you would need to inherit IDisposable and call .Dispose() on it when you are done or you will fill up your app pool. You could do something like this in a data manager class:

```
public void RunQuery(string query)
{
    using(OracleConnection conn= new OracleConnection(connString))
    using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        //do your data transaction here
     }
}
```

That would let you pass queries to a single place to be handled. Still not a great solution but will let you keep it in one place. To use it:

```
new YourDataClass().RunQuery("INSERT...");
```

You would need a few different classes to handle things like selects, etc to return data if needed.

Edit: This is just conceptual. You would have a single data class and just send queries to it. Then you aren't reproducing the same connection code everywhere. You'll need to add more to this to have it cover all aspects of interfacing with your database but this is the general concept. This is written in one class and used over and over in your application. Again, an ORM would be far better but this will accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
public class YourDataClass
{
    public void RunQuery(string query) //for add, update where you don't want to return anything, could add a second parameter to send in a List<SqlParameter> to add data.
    {
        using(OracleConnection conn= new OracleConnection(connString))
        using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //do your data transaction here

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public DataTable GetData(string query) //for selecting data
    {
        using(OracleConnection conn= new OracleConnection(connString))
        using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //do your data transaction here

            dt.Add(cmd); //add data to data table or dataset

            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen- I dont think we would like to use EF in near future. Can you explain how this works- new YourDataClass().RunQuery("INSERT...");